# Как преобразовать полученные данные метод post, в верхний регистр

Tags: php

Пока не понял как сделать, гуглил, находил разные методы, но мало знаний чтобы самому реализовать перевод всего что я получаю с импутов через метод post в верхний регистр.

**Кусок моего кода:**

```
 $_isAjax = Arr::get($_POST, 'ajax', 1);

    if (!empty($_isAjax)) {
      $data = Arr::extract(
        $_POST,
        array(
          'date',
          'time',
          'dkfio',
          'dkname',
          'dkotch',
          'sobstvinostran',
          'tipdok',
```

и в конце после есть $orders->values($data);

**Я находил такие варианты:**

```
$text = 'привет Мир!';
echo mb_strtoupper($text); // ПРИВЕТ МИР!

<?php
    $string = $_POST['stroka']; // записываем в переменную, то что введено в строке
    $string = strtoupper($string); // делаем буковки большими
    echo $string; // распечатываем
?>
```

**strtolower()** - Преобразует строку в нижний регистр

**ucfirst()** - Преобразует первый символ строки в верхний регистр

**ucwords()** - Преобразует в верхний регистр первый символ каждого слова в строке

**mb_strtoupper()** - Приведение строки к верхнему регистру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php).
Пример кода:

```
function toUpper(&$el, $key) {
    $el = mb_strtoupper($el);
}
       
array_walk($data, 'toUpper');
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d865b481b0c8222e51962733632aed3d901fcf09).

Comment: Спасибо, работает.